# Prove that $T$ is bounded if $\langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, T^*y \rangle$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose $T: L^2(\mathbb R^d) \to L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ is a linear operator, and there exists $T^*: L^2(\mathbb R^d) \to L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, T^*y \rangle$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb R^d$. Prove that $T$ is bounded.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I think it says that $T$ is "invertible" if it is bounded, which makes sense. I have no idea how to prove it though. Right now I'm a bit confused by the inner product. We haven't seen anything in class about how to treat a linear operator in an inner product, so I assume that the reason we are restricted to $L^2$ is that it is self-dual. I don't see how that helps at all though. Any help at all will be appreciated.

EDIT: So I managed to solve the other 5 questions from this same homework without any major issues, but I still have no idea how do solve this one. The homework has already been handed in, but I want to understand this question. My lecturer is away at a conference, so it will be a week and a half before I can ask him about it. Everyone else I've asked just tells me to apply the closed graph theorem, just like Topoguy says in his answer. The problem is that I don't understand how to show that the graph is closed. I assume it's something really obvious that I'm missing. Could someone explain to me why everyone seems to think it's really obvious to apply the closed graph theorem to this problem?

Comment: Boundedness is equivalent to continuity in the norm topologies, so no, $T$ is not invertible if it is bounded (take for example, the zero map, which is continuous but clearly not invertible).

Comment: In a Hilbert Space $H$, is it true that a sequence $a_k$ tends to $0_H$ iff $\langle a_k,y \rangle$ tends to zero for all $y \in H$?? Because if this holds true, then for any sequence $x_k \to 0$, we'd know that for any $ y \in H$, $\langle Tx_k, y \rangle = \langle x_k  , T^*y \rangle \leq ||x_k|| \cdot ||T^*y|| \to 0$ and this would imply that $Tx_k \to 0$. But you'd need that first statement to hold.

Comment: @Shalop: No, this is not true. Consider e.g. $H =\ell^2 (\Bbb{N})$ and $a_k = e_k$, where the $e_k$ are the "standard basis", i.e. $(e_k)_n =0$ for $k\neq n$ and $1$ otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's equivalent to prove $T$ is continuous. One theorem to get $T$ is continuous is the closed graph theorem. So can you show the graph of  ($x$,$Tx$) is closed?
Suppose $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $Tx_n \rightarrow y$ and we want to show $Tx=y$. 
Indded, $\langle Tx, z \rangle = \langle x, T^*z \rangle =\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle x_n, T^*z \rangle = \lim_{n \to \infty}\langle Tx_n, z \rangle= \langle y, z \rangle $.
Therefore, $\langle Tx-y,z\rangle=0$ for all $z\in L^2$ and hence $Tx=y$ which means the graph is closed, i.e. $T$ is continuous.

Comment: How do I do that? I would have to show that the graph contains all of its limit points, but I don't see how. This problem is making me feel really stupid. I can't see how any of the individual "pieces" ($L^2$, inner products, linear operators) have anything to do with the goal.

Comment: @Johanna The closed graph theorem says the following: if from $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $Tx_n\rightarrow y$ it follows that $Tx=y$, then $T$ is bounded, if $T$ is a linear map between Banach spaces.

Comment: @VincentBoelens I know that's what the theorem says, I just don't understand how any of the things I'm given bring me any closer to showing that the graph is closed so I can apply the theorem.

Comment: @Johanna Why not? This answer shows the graph of $T$ is closed.

Comment: @VincentBoelens I edited the answer after Johanna's comment, so maybe that's why.

Comment: @Johanna You're welcome. Glad I can help.=）

Comment: Why is the closed graph theorem required? Can't we characterise a continuous function by: For each convergent sequence ${x_n} \rightarrow x$ we should have $T(x_n) \rightarrow T(x)$? And that is exactly what we have shown.